# How to make image fit to its div CSS

Tags: html, css, image, web-frontend

Let's suppose I have the following code:

```css
img {
  max-widht: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div width="500" height="500">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150">
</div>
```

This works fine for all images if with `width` or `height` higher than 500px.
But with smaller images, the image will not cover the `div`.
Is there a CSS way to force the image to be a least `width: 100%` or `height: 100%` regardless its original size ?

EDIT :
This solution by [disinfor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172189/disinfor) worked for me.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: remove `max-width` and `max-height` - that's basically saying max-width of the original image. Do this `width: 100%; height: auto;` This will make the image 100% width of whatever container it's in, but not distort the image vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The reason smaller images (in your case, smaller than 500px wide) don't fill the whole space, is because `max-width` means "max width of the actual image." So if you use `width: 100%` instead, the image will fill the space of its container.

Using `height: auto` will ensure the image doesn't get stretched/distort vertically.

Proof of concept:

```css
.normal, .land, .port, .fit {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.land img,
div.port img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.fit img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="fit">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/500x750">
</div>

<div class="fit">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/50x100">
</div>

<div class="normal">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/75x10">
</div>

<div class="normal">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/10x75">
</div>

<div class="land">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/75x10">
</div>

<div class="port">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/10x75">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's for your help. The problem with `height: auto` is that it does not prevent the image to be higher than the `div`. If I have an image of size 500*800 for example, width will be 100% so 500px, and height auto so 800px. In this case, height should be 100% and width auto.

Comment: @aurerob You can set height to 100% if you want to, but no matter what, the largest dimension will be filled first - the other will then distort

Comment: height:auto is not needed unless set elsewhere and needs to be reset. Also, if the image is a landscape , it will not cover the bottom part , if it is a portrait, it will overflow. object-fit seems to be a good compromise and allows to choose how to clip image if not a square  ;)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position to test compromise for image which are not squares

Comment: @G-Cyr true. I guess I always add it as a precaution. I agree with the object-fit as well. I updated my code to show how the images actually react with `height: 100%`

Comment: I guess the op has to make a compromise somewhere . clip image or use only square images ;)

Comment: absolutely. I think that's really the crux of this issue...there needs to be a compromise

Comment: @G-Cyr I updated the answer to include `object-fit` for the compromise. As a caveat: object fit does not work in IE11 and it has only `img` support in Edge 16 and up

Comment: The `object-fit` works indeed. I was trying to use it with `max-width` and `max-height`, that's why it couldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div width="500" height="500">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/250/150">
</div>
```

Comment: Since you took part of the code from my answer, how does this differ from what I already answered with? And your code doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but `object-fit: cover;` does not seem to change anything.

Comment: You should explain a bit more the use of object-fit, it seems to me the best compromise here ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you answered to your own question!
You have a Div! => width:500px and height: 500px!
when an image is larger than this size, Max-width and max-height can work correctly!
but when your image is smaller, max-width can't help you, because image width is smaller than 500px!
for example you have an Image => width:300px. max-width:100% is equal to 300px!
then you can change your code like this:

```
<div>
   <img src="#" alt="Alternate Text" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</div>
```

but if you want a responsive Image:

```
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;">
   <img src="#" alt="Alternate Text" style="width:500px;height:auto;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size` CSS rule if you put your image to background:

### css

```
    .block {
        background: url(my_picture.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

### html

```
    <div width="500" height="500" class="block"></div>
```

Comment: I have to use `<img>` because I use a map on it. Thanks anyway for the answer !